# An argument was not provided whenever I subscribe a function to a service

Tags: angular, angular-data

I am trying to subscribe my function to an even emitter, but I get

> An argument for 'eprompt' was not provided

I am new to this one that's why I really don't know any workaround solutions.

```js
     console.log(listtasksobs);
     this.listtask  = listtasksobs;
   })


   if (this.eventEmitterService.subsVar==undefined){
     this.eventEmitterService.subsVar = this.eventEmitterService
                                            .invokeTaskEditFunction
                                            .subscribe(()=>{


       //PROBLEM HERE
       this.editprompt(); //<<--- it shows : An argument for 'eprompt' was not provided
     });
   }
 }


 //load-editpromptlist
 editprompt(eprompt:taskdb): void {
   this.epromptshow = eprompt;

   const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TaskeditpromptComponent, {
     width: '650px',

   });

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     console.log('The dialog was closed');
   });
 }
```

Comment: Well, yes, you *aren’t* passing any argument when calling the function…

Answer (score 0):

Your `editprompt()` function take an `eprompt` parameter. You need to pass this parameter into the function when you call it. For example `this.editprompt(yourParameter)`. Alternatively you can set a default value or make the parameter optional.

Optional

`editprompt(eprompt?) {}`

Default Value

`editprompt(eprompt = 'value') {}`